# mySQL: проверка значения на "пустоту"

Tags: mysql

Нужно проверить значение поля. Если в нем содержится:
- пустая строка ''
- либо строка состоящая ли любого количества пробелов
- либо NULL
то, вернуть 1, иначе - 0.

Как бы это изящнее сделать с точки зрения производительности и компактности кода?

На ум пока приходят только два способа:

```
SET @a=NULL;
#SET @a='';
#SET @a='   ';

# первый способ:
SELECT @a IS NULL OR TRIM(@a)='';

# второй способ:
SELECT CONCAT_WS('',TRIM(@a))='';
```

Comment: Если часто приходится делать, может стоит написать свою функцию?

Comment: `trim(ifnull(@a,''))=''`